# Optimizing embark generation for maximum number of crops

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I'm interested to see if it is possible to tune a world to generate an embark site which supports all or as many as possible above-ground crops. This means it should at least have biomes that are (in order of importance):

- Tropical Grasslands (6 plants require)
- Temperate Grasslands (3 plants require)
- Good (Sun berry)
- Tropical Dry Broadleaf Forest (tomato, buckwheat)
- Evil (Whip vine)
- Tropical wetlands (papyrus)
- Tropical Savanna (fonio)

Most other plants aren't as picky: reading the wiki: with just a temperate and tropical biome of any kind, all plants but these 15 should be satisfied.

What would be the best way to configure advanced world generation parameters to get a world with a varied enough patchwork of biomes near the temperate/tropical transition to make such a thing probable to occur?